# WordPress: Convert comments to Posts when approved

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, comments, posts

I'm using the function below to convert WP-comments to WP-posts. I want it to be fired when "approving" a comment. (now it is whenever the plug-in is activated in WP).
So really I'm wondering how to ad my function to this action from line 47 of the edit-comments.php:

```
foreach ( $comment_ids as $comment_id ) { // Check the permissions on each
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_comment', $comment_id ) )
            continue;

        switch ( $doaction ) {
            case 'approve' :
                wp_set_comment_status( $comment_id, 'approve' );
                $approved++;
                break;
    [...]
   }
}
```

Plug-in function:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'convert_to_posts' );

function convert_to_posts(){

        $comments = get_comments();

        foreach($comments as $comment) 
        {


                $post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
                $title = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'title', true );
                $content = $comment->comment_content;
                $my_post = array(
                     'post_title' => $title,
                     'post_content' => $content,
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                     'post_author' => 1
                );      
               wp_insert_post( $my_post );
               // wp_delete_comment( $comment->comment_ID );
        }

    }
```